# Querying nested array in cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Having list of documents as below mentioned.

**Document1:**

```
 {
    id:1,
    PostList:[
     {
         postname:"aaa",
         lastdatetime:2017-07-13T17:10:25+05:30,
         sname:"sas"
     },
     {
         postname:"aaa1",
         lastdatetime:2017-07-14T17:10:25+05:30,
         sname:"sasadd"
     },
     {
         postname:"aaa2",
         lastdatetime:2017-07-10T17:10:25+05:30,
         sname:"weq"
     }
     ]
}
```

**Document2:**

```
 {
        id:2,
        PostList:[
         {
             postname:"aaa",
             lastdatetime:2017-07-13T17:10:25+05:30,
             sname:"sas"
         },
         {
             postname:"aaa1",
             lastdatetime:2017-07-14T17:10:25+05:30,
             sname:"sasadd"
         },
         {
             postname:"aaa2",
             lastdatetime:2017-07-10T17:10:25+05:30,
             sname:"weq"
         }
         ]
}
```

I need a list of postnames which is equal to "aaa" with orderby lastdatetime.

I am able to get query

```
select f.lastdatetime,f.postname
from c 
join f in c.PostList 
where f.postname='aaa'
```

But I need to get the list with orderby lastdatetime.

When I try the below query, I am getting an error

> Order-by over correlated collections is not supported

```
select f.lastdatetime,f.postname
from c 
join f in c.PostList 
where f.postname='aaa' ORDER BY f.lastdatetime ASC
```

Does anybody have an idea to get through?

Comment: This is the limitation of query today. But, we are working on to enable this scenario in future.

Comment: @RafatSarosh is there an issue we can track for this?

Comment: @mano Hi,any progress now?

Comment: @Jay Gong  no. Still in same place.

Comment: @mano Have you tried my workaround? Any further steps or other errors?

Comment: @mano Hi,any updates? Does my answer helps you?

Comment: @Jay Gong  Sorry. i am working on some other workaround like changing json format change. since its need for other requirement too. thanks.

Comment: @mano All right.

Answer (score 6):

As @Rafat Sarosh said in the comment :`Order-by over correlated collections is not supported`  and it will be enable in the future.

However, I suggest a workaround for you to track for your solution: use [Azure Cosmos DB UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#udf).

You could pass the results of your query as parameters to the UDF for sorting processing.

***Query Sql:***

```
select f.lastdatetime,f.postname
 from c 
join f in c.PostList 
where f.postname='aaa'
```

***UDF sample code:***

```
function userDefinedFunction(arr){
    var i = arr.length, j;
    var tempExchangVal;
    while (i > 0) {
        for (j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j].lastdatetime < arr[j + 1].lastdatetime) {
                tempExchangVal = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = tempExchangVal;
            }
        }
        i--;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Hope it helps you.